# Use of 'kommen' to mean 'bekommen'

Tags: translation

I have come across this usage in the ARD drama [Sehnsucht nach Rimini](https://www.ardmediathek.de/ard/player/Y3JpZDovL2hyLW9ubGluZS84NjM5NA/sehnsucht-nach-rimini).

Context:
A travel company is experiencing financial hardship. A business competitor is proposing a merger. The owner of the company is arguing with her daughter about the proposed merger. The mother suspects that the competitor has ulterior motives. The daughter is more open to the competitor's proposal.

At 15:52, the following dialogues occur:

> Mutter: "Er will billig an die Busse ran!"
>
> Tochter: "Das käme er bei einer Zwangversteigerung."

The meaning is obvious: The competitor could get hold of the buses anyway at a forced auction (if this financial situation continues).

My question is with the use of 'kommen' in the second sentence. 'kommen' seems to be used here to mean 'bekommen'. Is this standard usage? I couldn't find this in the dictionaries I tried.

Comment: I guess, it is assumed for the reader/listener, to supplement *kommen* in the mother's statement resulting in *rankommen*, so *käme* from the daughter connects to that verb. As written I consider both sentences as colloquial (*ran* on its own is sufficient to indicate that), and would not recommend to imitate this pattern.

Comment: @guidot, please do not answer in comments

Comment: Just for completeness, the actual dialogue is _"Der will billig an unsere Busse ran!" - "Das käme er bei einer Zwangversteigerung **auch**."_ which adds the meaning of "anyway". But the construction works the same way with or without "auch".

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's neither about [*kommen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/kommen) nor about [*bekommen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bekommen), but about the separable verb [*rankommen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/rankommen). In the following sentence, *ran* is an [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)) of *rankommen*:

> Mutter: „Er will billig an die Busse ran(*kommen*)!“

The answer could have been

> Tochter: „*Ran* käme er bei einer Zwangsversteigerung.“

Instead, the demonstrative pronoun *das* was used, to emphasize that the entire action of *billig rankommen* is referred to. In this special case, the separable prefix must be omitted.

> Tochter: „*Das <s>ran</s>* käme er bei einer Zwangversteigerung.“

Comment: Thanks, I haven't come across this type of construction before.

Comment: _Das_ is a substitute here for "billig ran".